# Trigonometry question: Find in simplest surd form: $\cos 195^{\circ}$

Tags: trigonometry

Find in simplest surd form: $\cos 195^{\circ}$.

Ive recently been doing the trigonometry topic form textbook and have oftenly come across these questions. Can someone please justify how you do this question? Ive tried many times but no luck.

Comment: I suppose the angle is in degrees here? Otherwise, $\cos 195$ will probably be transcendental.

Comment: yes its 195 degrees

Comment: In that case, it's $-\cos 15°$, or $-\cos \frac{\pi}{12}$. You probably know $\cos \frac{\pi}{6}$, and the doubling formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that we are working with angles in degrees.

Hint:

$$\cos(195) = \cos(180 + 15)$$

Another hint:

> Now split $\cos(180 + 15)$ using $\cos(A+B) = \cos(A)\cos(B)-\sin(A)\sin(B)$.

And another:

> Substitute $\sin(180) = 0$ and $\cos(180) = -1$.

Nearly done:

> Notice that $\cos(15) = \cos(30/2)$ and remember that $\cos(2A) = 2\cos^{2}(A) - 1$.

Now draw the 30/60/90 triangle and evaluate.

Comment: can you please tell me what happens to the 15 afterwards?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but how does cos 30/2 fit in the criteria of cos2A?

Comment: Hmm, possibly I should have written it as $\cos(30) = \cos(15\times2)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos 195^\circ=\cos(180^\circ+15^\circ)=-\cos15^\circ$$ as $\cos(180^\circ+\theta)=-\cos\theta$

$$\implies \cos 195^\circ=-\cos(60^\circ-45^\circ)$$

Now, we know  $\cos(A-B)=\cos A\cos B+\sin A\sin B$

$\cos60^\circ=\frac12,\sin60^\circ=\frac{\sqrt3}2, \cos45^\circ=\sin45^\circ=\frac1{\sqrt2}$

---

Alternatively, $$\cos 195^\circ=\cos(150^\circ+45^\circ)=...$$

As $\cos(180^\circ-\theta)=-\cos\theta$ and $\sin(180^\circ-\theta)=\sin\theta$

$$\cos150^\circ=\cos(180^\circ-30^\circ)=-\cos30^\circ=...$$

$$\sin150^\circ=\sin(180^\circ-30^\circ)=\sin30^\circ=...$$

Answer (score 0):

I'll add to the discussion by providing more hints.

\begin{align*}
\cos(a + b) & = \cos(a)\cos(b) - \sin(a)\sin(b) \\
\cos^2(a/2) & = \frac{1 + \cos a}2 \\
\sin^2(a/2) & = \frac{1 - \cos a}2 \\
\cos(9\pi/8) & = \cos(\pi + (\pi/4)/2)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

We need to know some basic angle's values, and then use some trigonometric identities:

$$\frac{\sqrt3}2=\cos30^\circ=\cos(2\cdot 15^\circ)=2\cos^215^\circ-1\implies\cos^215^\circ=\frac{\frac{\sqrt3}2+1}2=\frac{\sqrt3+2}4\implies$$

$$\cos15^\circ=\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt3+2}}2$$

and from here

$$\cos 195^\circ=\cos(180^\circ+15^\circ)=\cos180^\circ\cos15^\circ-\sin180^\circ\sin15^\circ=-\cos15^\circ=-\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt3+2}}2$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos 195^\circ$$
$$\cos (270^\circ-75^\circ)$$
since $\cos (270^\circ-\theta)=-\sin\theta$
$$-\sin 75^\circ$$
$$-\sin(45^\circ+30^\circ)$$

use property: $\sin (A+B)=\sin A\cos B+\cos A\sin B$
$$-\left(\sin 45^\circ \cos 30^\circ+\cos 45^\circ \sin 30^\circ\right)$$
$$-\left(\dfrac {1}{\sqrt 2}\cdot \dfrac {\sqrt 3}{2}+\dfrac {1}{\sqrt 2}\cdot \dfrac 12\right)$$
$$-\left(\dfrac {\sqrt 3}{2\sqrt 2}+\dfrac {1}{2\sqrt 2}\right)$$
$$-\left(\dfrac {1+\sqrt 3}{2\sqrt 2}\right)$$